# Freeswitch prevent hangup

Tags: freeswitch, pbx

Can somebody tell me how to prevent my freeswitch extension from hangup after playing some music?

Here is my extension:

```
<include>
    <extension name="welcome_ivr" continue="true">
            <condition field="destination_number" expression="^411$">
                <action application="answer" />
                <action application="playback" data="/usr/local/funny.wav"/>
            </condition>
    </extension>
</include>
```

and to this extension i call a script which look likes this:

```
def handler(session, args):
    logging.basicConfig(filename='/tmp/test.log',level=logging.INFO)

    while session.ready():
        logging.info("string")
    return
```

So after the song is played it hangup. How can i prevent that. I want the channel stay open also after the song is played and only hangup if i want to hangup (session.hangup())

Hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was very simple. I just change the extension to play the song endless.

```
<action application="endless_playback" data="/usr/local/funny.wav"/>
```

So i can do stuff how long i want.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, once the song is over it's "done" so it hangs up.

Have it go to park after, then it will stay open until the park timeout.

`<action application="park" />`